# Maven Multi-module project - SpringBoot - Kafka Consumer Not connecting to Broker

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to build a Kafka Consumer using Spring Boot. It's a multi-module Maven project where consumer-app is the SpringBoot application and rest of the modules are added as dependencies to the parent project.

With this, I am able to build the project and run the app as well. But the app is not connecting to the Kafka broker (bootstrap server on my local).

Log ends as this:

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.3.12.RELEASE)

2022-06-28 20:26:50.849  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.c.c.c.CardConsumerApplication        : Starting CardConsumerApplication on WorkIsOn with PID 17284 (C:\Users\myuser\Workspace\card-consumer\card-consumer\target\classes started by myuser in C:\Users\myuser\Workspace\card-consumer)
2022-06-28 20:26:50.851  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.c.c.c.CardConsumerApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-06-28 20:26:50.900  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-06-28 20:26:50.901  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-06-28 20:26:51.778  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2022-06-28 20:26:51.784  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-28 20:26:51.785  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
2022-06-28 20:26:51.850  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-28 20:26:51.850  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 949 ms
2022-06-28 20:26:51.977  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-06-28 20:26:52.157  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-06-28 20:26:52.182  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2022-06-28 20:26:52.189  INFO 17284 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.c.c.c.CardConsumerApplication        : Started CardConsumerApplication in 1.688 seconds (JVM running for 3.215)
```

Now, I made another app with the code of Kafka consumer module in a non-multi-module Maven project, I am able to connect to the Kafka's bootstrap server and this app is able to get the message as well.

I have same SpringBoot configuration placed in both the application/project.

Please help me understand how to make this multi-module Maven app work.

Comment: Provide more details about the working module and the other one, on this way the engineers here will provide you a quick answers.

Comment: Your logs say nothing about the consumer being started. So, seems your consumer module is not actually used/started. A simple dependency addition in Maven will not do this. You will want to have some `@Service` or `@Component` that is used by the application scanner to start the consumer containers. That being said, multi-modules shouldn't matter (and I know they work correctly, when you configure them)

Comment: Kindly share your Spring Boot Starter Class. Looks like something is wrong with you CommandLiner or Runnable class.